# How to modify inner style of violin plot in Seaborn Python

Tags: python, seaborn, violin-plot

I'm plotting violin plot using seaborn.
but the color of mini box inside of each violin is arbitrary; black to gray.
I want to change the color of inner mini box as well as the line color of whisker.
Could you help me out?
Thank you in advance!